# What brand name service panel is this?

Tags: electrical

I live in a New Orleans double shotgun house that is 150 years old. The fuse box was removed in the late 1970s with a unknown brand of breaker box. I want to add a manual interlock for a portable generator circuit, but I am unsure of the box manufacturer. It was Gould and Croyse-Hinds Qp breakers. Can anyone ID this box?

[image: List item]

Comment: If you're going to be fiddling with it anyway, pull the cover. All should become clear.

Answer (score 1):

That beveled breaker handle (seen on the main and the oldest breakers) is the [distinctive look](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=crouse%20hinds%20breaker&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic7Z7e8fr_AhVTOEQIHROJCPkQ0pQJegQICRAB&biw=1459&bih=996&dpr=1#imgrc=gYeF5SXgaK5ILM) of a Crouse-Hinds breaker. So is the style of the sticker on the main.

This is solidly in the Murray MP lineage, which for vanity reasons Siemens renamed QP.  Siemens QP breakers are right for this panel.

The Type BR breaker is not approved for this panel (unless the panel labeling says otherwise) - the labeling is typically inside the front cover.

The mere sight of a Cutler-Hammer or Eaton logo isn't necessarily a problem, since they also make the Cutler Hammer/Eaton "***CL***" line, which is UL-***CL***assified for this panel (but not for Eaton BR panels).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing is that there is NO other signage or decals to signify what cabinet this is. There is another box right next to this one ( for a different address) same in every way but it has a Gould main braker. Which is why I used a siemens QP for the added circuit.

Comment: @Nawlins Yeah, nameless panels were pretty typical back in the day, except for the high-end panels from Cutler Hammer and Square D.  (and with Cutler Hammer you could tell from the sandalwood color). ITE and Gould were pretty close actually and are now all Siemens, wouldn't surprise me if their main failed and ITE was the replacement. There was some main-breaker horse trading. I have a Pushmatic panel with ITE main because Pushmatic never made a 200A breaker.